# Why is startActivity() not working in onRecieve()?

Tags: android, broadcast

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "This is the broadcast receiver");

        switch(intent.getAction()) {
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED: {
                mMeetingRoomDeviceSettings = SharedPreferenceManager.getSharedPreferenceValues(context);

                // If you need to launch on device restart.
                if(mMeetingRoomDeviceSettings.getLaunchOnBootup()) {
                    Intent configurationIntent = new Intent(context, ConfigureMeetingRoomActivity.class);

                    configurationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(configurationIntent);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Everything went fine.");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know why, but startActivity() does not start the activitiy at all.

The logs are getting displayed:

```
2020-03-06 15:19:06.523 8833-8833/com.eurofins.android.myapplication I/MeetingRoomBroadcast: This is the broadcast receiver
2020-03-06 15:19:06.571 8833-8833/com.eurofins.android.myapplication I/MeetingRoomBroadcast: Everything went fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

To start an activity from broadcast receiver following is code snippet:

```
Intent configurationIntent= new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ConfigureMeetingRoomActivity.class);
context.startActivity(configurationIntent);
```

You have used context instead of context.getApplicationContext(). I am not sure about this,but you can try..

Or just simply try to start activity without any flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below flag with intent and it should work.

```
configurationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```

Or if that does not work

Try to open launcher activity from there redirect to your activity using some put extra from intent.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Even I thought, it was FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK that was causing the issue. Unfortunately, not.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check other option too.

Answer (score 0):

Intent i= new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.packagename","com.packagename.ConfigureMeetingRoomActivity.class");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);

You need to set your package name and your class name

Comment: Tried scheduling a service too.. with JobService.